# do_shortcode breaks formatting

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Has anyone encountered this problem before?  Directly calling the shortcode from WordPress and calling the shortcode via functions.php yields different results.

Refer to this [image: img:]

Image 1 has decent design since it was invoked directly from WordPress UI while Image 2 somehow messed up the design because it was invoked from php (functions.php).

Additional info:

- Current theme is DIVI
- Shortcode/Plugin used is TableMaster

To add further information, I have this line of shortcode in WordPress (as seen on image 2).

```
[get_blogs_sc]
```

And on my functions.php, I have this function,

```
function GetActiveBlogs($i)
{ 

    $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

    if (preg_match('/sites/',$actual_link))
    {

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        if ($user_id > 0) 
        {

            echo do_shortcode('[tablemaster buttons="true" datatables="true" class="black-header-gray-alternate-rows" sql="some select where user_id = '.user_id.'"]', true);
        }
    }
}


add_shortcode('get_blogs_sc', 'GetActiveBlogs');
```

But when I use the shortcode directly from WordPress:

```
[tablemaster buttons="true" datatables="true" class="black-header-gray-alternate-rows" sql="some select where user_id = 14]
```

the display on my page looks good (as seen on image 1)

My objective on putting the shortcode in php-layer is for me to be able to capture the logged-in user from WordPress.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to diagnose what the issue is only from images ! without what the code really says.
but let's know what difference between `do_shortcode` and `add_shortcode`

```
do_shortcode( string $content, bool $ignore_html = false )
```

Search content for shortcodes and filter shortcodes through their hooks.
it return (string) Content with shortcodes filtered out.

```
// Use shortcode in a PHP file (outside the post editor).
echo do_shortcode( '' );
```

for more information check [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/)

while `add_shortcode` Adds a hook for a shortcode tag.

```
<?php add_shortcode( $tag , $func ); ?>
```

$tag
(string) (required) Shortcode tag to be searched in post content
Default: None
$func
(callable) (required) Hook to run when shortcode is found
Default: None

it return nothing but when you write shortcode tag in post area it apply the function of shortcode for more information check [Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

Comment: I've added more information on the question. Sorry for missing some details.

Comment: may be you should use div with class="wrap" and wrap your printed code inside ,you can identify what is the difference between 2 cases by inspect [F12]